# VMWare vRealize Operations Manager admin password error

Tags: vmware

I have an interesting problem about "admin" user and it's password on vRealize Operations Manager. I change the admin's password with

```
$VMWARE_PYTHON_BIN $VCOPS_BASE/../vmware-vcopssuite/utilities/sliceConfiguration/bin/vcopsSetAdminPassword.py --reset
```

command. I can connect with ssh with admin@vropsserver to vrops appliance and there is no error about password and I can connect to web client just once and I cannot connect second time via web GUI with same password. I can connect at first time but if I try connect second time I get "Invalid user/password" error. When I check the login failure count I just can see "0" always. My vRealize Operations Manager version is 6.4.

Comment: I rebooted the appliance and problem is solved. But I don't know what is causing this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. There is a file named `adminuser.properties` in appliance and this file blocks new login because of login failure count. I added a `sed` command to crontab:

```
sed -i '/failed_attemts/d' /storage/vcops/user/conf/adminuser.properties
```

I think so there is a script try login as admin and I can't find it. But this solution works for now.